# Saleor Platform running, storefront wont start the server

Tags: javascript, webpack, saleor

I've used the saleor platform method, with docker and dashboard and everything else works properly, but not the frontend, any idea how to debug this, this is the output of the last command

```
storefront_1  | > saleor-site@2.11.0 start /app
storefront_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=develop webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --watch --port 3000 --mode development --hotOnly "--hostname" "0.0.0.0"
storefront_1  |
storefront_1  | Starting type checking service...
storefront_1  | Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
storefront_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3000/
storefront_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
storefront_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app
storefront_1  | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
storefront_1  | Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
mailhog_1     | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
storefront_1  | Type checking in progress...
storefront_1  | ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
storefront_1  | ⚠ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 8bbc7119559a66ddb40a
storefront_1  | Version: webpack 4.42.1
storefront_1  | Time: 65254ms
storefront_1  | Built at: 05/29/2021 11:15:57 AM
storefront_1  |                                                   Asset       Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
storefront_1  |                                         images/amex.svg   3.81 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                   images/arrow-back.svg  404 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                        images/arrow.svg  127 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                            images/breadcrumbs-arrow.svg  198 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                               images/carousel-arrow.svg  223 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                         images/cart.svg    1.3 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                     images/discover.svg   1.77 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                images/facebook-icon.svg  369 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/android-chrome-144x144.png   4.16 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png   5.62 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/android-chrome-256x256.png   7.54 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                images/favicons/android-chrome-36x36.png   1.03 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/android-chrome-384x384.png   13.4 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                images/favicons/android-chrome-48x48.png   1.33 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png   19.5 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                images/favicons/android-chrome-72x72.png   1.99 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                images/favicons/android-chrome-96x96.png    2.7 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |          images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-1024x1024.png   57.9 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png   3.19 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png   3.35 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png   4.14 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png   4.41 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-167x167.png   4.85 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png   5.31 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png    1.6 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png   1.67 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png   1.99 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |              images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png   2.14 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |        images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png   5.31 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                    images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png   5.31 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  | images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-1182x2208.png     49 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  | images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-1242x2148.png   85.9 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  | images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-1496x2048.png   95.4 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  | images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-1536x2008.png    114 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |   images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png   11.3 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |  images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-640x1096.png   30.7 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |   images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png   29.7 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |  images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-748x1024.png   32.2 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |  images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-750x1294.png   38.9 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |  images/favicons/apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png   38.3 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                       images/favicons/browserconfig.xml  481 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                       images/favicons/coast-228x228.png   6.99 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                       images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png  481 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                       images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png  910 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                             images/favicons/favicon.ico   32.5 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                 images/favicons/firefox_app_128x128.png   3.88 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                 images/favicons/firefox_app_512x512.png     22 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                   images/favicons/firefox_app_60x60.png   1.84 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                           images/favicons/manifest.json   1.38 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                         images/favicons/manifest.webapp  351 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                      images/favicons/mstile-144x144.png   4.16 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                      images/favicons/mstile-150x150.png   8.69 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                      images/favicons/mstile-310x150.png   9.44 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                      images/favicons/mstile-310x310.png   22.4 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                        images/favicons/mstile-70x70.png   3.51 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                images/favicons/yandex-browser-50x50.png   1.38 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |            images/favicons/yandex-browser-manifest.json  165 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                      images/garbage.svg  914 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                              images/hamburger-hover.svg  360 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                    images/hamburger.svg  252 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                               images/instagram-icon.svg  879 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                          images/jcb.svg   1.74 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                   images/logo-small.svg  824 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                         images/logo.svg   2.12 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                      images/maestro.svg  413 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                   images/mastercard.svg  413 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                     images/no-photo.svg   5.19 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                   images/quote-icon.svg  380 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                       images/search.svg  704 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                images/subcategories.svg  128 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                 images/twitter-icon.svg  696 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                         images/user.svg   1.85 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                         images/visa.svg   1.17 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                            images/x.svg  289 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                 images/youtube-icon.svg  637 bytes          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                              index.html   4.75 KiB          [emitted]
storefront_1  |                                               js/app.js   9.25 MiB     app  [emitted]        app
storefront_1  |                                           js/app.js.map    8.4 MiB     app  [emitted] [dev]  app
storefront_1  | Entrypoint app = js/app.js js/app.js.map
storefront_1  | [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js ./src/index.tsx 52 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js] 809 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/extends.js] 427 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js] 49 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@hot-loader/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@saleor/sdk/lib/index.js] 5.2 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@sentry/apm/esm/index.js] 325 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/@sentry/browser/esm/index.js] 793 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/react-alert/dist/esm/react-alert.js] 12.3 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/react-gtm-module/dist/index.js] 251 bytes {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/react-hot-loader/index.js] 1.24 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js] 9.76 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:3000] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 4.29 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./node_modules/webpack/hot/only-dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/only-dev-server.js 2.52 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  | [./src/index.tsx] 4.38 KiB {app} [built]
storefront_1  |     + 1485 hidden modules
storefront_1  |
storefront_1  | WARNING in EnvironmentPlugin - GTM_ID environment variable is undefined.
storefront_1  |
storefront_1  | You can pass an object with default values to suppress this warning.
storefront_1  | See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin for example.
storefront_1  | Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
storefront_1  |      1 asset
storefront_1  |     Entrypoint undefined = index.html
storefront_1  |     [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 866 bytes {0} [built]
storefront_1  |     [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 530 KiB {0} [built]
storefront_1  |     [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
storefront_1  |     [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
storefront_1  | Child webapp-webpack-plugin:
storefront_1  |      1 asset
storefront_1  |     Entrypoint favicon.png = b69c9faae52434d05cae
storefront_1  |     [./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/app/node_modules/.cache/webapp-webpack-plugin"}!./node_modules/webapp-webpack-plugin/src/loader.js?{"prefix":"images/favicons/","options":{"appDescription":"Storefront for the Saleor e-commerce platform","appName":"Saleor","background":"#ddd","developerURL":null,"display":"standalone","theme_color":"#333","version":"2.11.0","developerName":"Mirumee"},"path":"/"}!./src/images/favicon.png] 1.06 MiB {favicon.png} [built]
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:00] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:00] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1350
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:14] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:14] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1350
mailhog_1     | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:39] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:39] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 477
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:49] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:16:49] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2543
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:17:23] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:17:23] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 87
mailhog_1     | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:18] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:19] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35562
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_06_hb65yCt-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7686
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_01-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7798
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleor-digital-03_4-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 13601
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_02_PZyWi7S-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7085
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_cl_bogo02_1-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 13127
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_02-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7085
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_05-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 8576
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_cl_boot07_1-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 10543
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_04-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7448
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_cuschion01-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14283
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleor-digital-03_5-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 15558
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_paints_05-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 9779
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_paints_04-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 10111
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleor-digital-03_2-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 13974
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_cl_bogo03_1-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14276
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_paints_01-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 9157
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_06-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7686
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleor-digital-03_3-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 14931
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:20] "GET /media/__sized__/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_03-thumbnail-255x255.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7511
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:22] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9847
mailhog_1     | [APIv1] KEEPALIVE /api/v1/events
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:28] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:29] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 35562
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:30] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12422
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:30] "GET /media/products/saleordemoproduct_fd_juice_06_hb65yCt.png HTTP/1.1" 200 69727
api_1         | [29/May/2021 11:18:32] "POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 341
storefront_1  | No type errors found
storefront_1  | Version: typescript 3.8.2, eslint 7.2.0
storefront_1  | Time: 256520ms
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing similar issue. Updating build command for storefront in docker-compose.yml file fixed it.

Change "--hostname" argument name to "--host" as used in dashboard.

Before:

```
storefront:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-storefront
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --hostname 0.0.0.0
```

After:

```
storefront:
    build:
      context: ./saleor-storefront
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-storefront/:/app:cached
      - /app/node_modules/
    command: npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0
```